# Hardest problems to approximate

Tags: approximation-hardness, clique

Under some assumptions, it is [hard to approximate MAX-CLIQUE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/548522) within a factor $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Are there any other problems that are known to be equally hard to approximate? I'm particularly interested in unweighted problems.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me how you're hoping to get an apples to apples comparison. Are you asking for graph problems and $n$ is always the number of vertices? Is $n$ input size (I am not sure now if Hastad's proof works for sparse graphs, but I assume it does). Is $n$ the ratio between the smallest and largest solution of fixed size instances? Seems "unfair" to compare MaxCut, where all optimal solutions lie in $[|E|/2, |E|]$, and MaxClique. Notions like approximation resistance and advantage over random make more sense to me.

Comment: Moreover, there are problems, like discrepancy of a hypergraph, where determining if OPT is positive or 0 is hard. So the approximation ratio is infinite. Do such examples answer your question?

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be a graph problem. I think it is entirely fair to compare MAX-CLIQUE with MAX-CUT. MAX-CUT has a constant factor approximation.

Comment: If you think otherwise, please explain in an answer both your preferred notion of hardness and a list some 'hardest' problems.

Comment: maybe MaxCut was a bad example. take Max-E3-SAT: there is a factor $7/8$ approximation, but it's entirely trivial because all optimal solutions are in $[7m/8, m]$. that aside, does every problem for which deciding OPT > 0 is NP-Hard automatically qualify as 'hardest to approximate' (approximation ratio is at least $\infty$) according to your criteria?

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps we can restrict it to problems where the optimal solution belongs to {1,...,n}. Otherwise, I am not sure how to make the question precise and meaningful at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unweighted problems, The Nearest Codeword problem in coding theory is known to be very hard to approximate. It is [NP-hard to approximate](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/2000/85221-CS.pdf) to within
a factor $n^{ \Omega(1)/ \log \log n}$.

Another hard to approximate problem is the longest path problem in directed graphs. [Björklund, Husfeldt, and Khanna](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1202&context=cis_papers) showed that longest path in directed graphs is hard to approximate to within better than a $n^{1-\epsilon}$ factor for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Also, Approximating [Closest Vector in a lattice](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00493-003-0019-y) to within almost polynomial factors is NP-Hard.

Finally, [minimum independent dominating set](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019093900222) of a graph is not approximable within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Answer (score 7):

A similar hardness result is known for the inapproximability of chromatic number [1]. Independent set is hard to approximate as well, since it is $\mathsf{MAX\text{-}CLIQUE}$ on the complement graph. Some problems that are easier to approximate include vertex cover, (connected) dominating set, feedback vertex set, TSP and Steiner tree.

---

[1] [Zuckerman, David. "Linear degree extractors and the inapproximability of max clique and chromatic number." Proceedings of the thirty-eighth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing. ACM, 2006.](http://toc.nada.kth.se/articles/v003a006/v003a006.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Min TSP is harder to approximate than maximum clique. For the general case of Min TSP, it is hard to approximate the minimum weight of TSP within better than [exponential factors](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/algs/tsp.pdf).

Comment: My answer for the OP before the edit.

Answer (score 4):

The title of this question does not match the content. As stated in the comments, there are some NP optimization problems for which *any* polynomial time approximation algorithm implies P = NP. Maybe you are looking for optimization problems that are not approximable within any polynomial factor, or that exhibit a threshold behavior? You may be looking for polyAPX-hard or polyAPX-complete problems.

polyAPX is the class of NP optimization problems that have a polynomial time approximation algorithm such that the measure of the approximate solution is within a polynomial factor of the optimal measure. In Theorem 2 of [this extended abstract](http://basepub.dauphine.fr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/4769/isaac04.pdf?sequence=2), you can see that the Maximum Independent Set problem is complete for polyAPX under PTAS reductions.

For more information on approximation-preserving reductions and approximability results, check out [the compendium of NP optimization problems](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/).